# Change the name of the drop folder for a TFS 2010 Build

Tags: workflow-foundation, tfsbuild

My auto builds are running fine, but after some versioning customization, the name of the folder for the build is just a ever increasing number (ie, 358,359,360...)

How can it get that set to the version number I made and set to the build name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of hte folder by default is set to the name of the build, which can be customized via the build definition.

If you've customized the workflow itself you may have inadvertently changed this behaviour.  Examine the workflow and under the Update Drop Location sequence there are 2 activities: Set Drop Location and Create the Drop Location which determine the folder path and create it.  By default the folder path is set to: BuildDetail.DropLocationRoot + "\" + BuildDetail.BuildDefinition.Name + "\" + BuildDetail.BuildNumber

The BuildNumber format is set in the build definition configuration, by default it is: $(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)

If nothing looks out of order, try running the build with Logging Verbosity set to Diagnostic under the Parameters tab and examine the build output.